# Unclear libpd abstraction path for iOS

Tags: libpd

I've created a cordova plugin using libpd.  Cordova uses a shared resource folder (called /www) and then copies all files to their respective OS.  I've noticed that with iOS when opening the main pd patch from the main bundle like this:

```
[PdBase openFile:@"/www/cordova.pd" path:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] ];
```

it opens the patch just fine but doesn't link any abstractions in the same path or those in [define -path ./ext].

However, if I copy the patches into the main bundle and open them independently from the cordova root /www folder like this:

```
[PdBase openFile:@"cordova.pd" path:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] ];
```

All abstractions are found and work just fine.  Why won't libpd link the abstraction path when opening a patch from a folder in the main bundle?